# Best Practices for Dependency Injection in Spring: Why does using @Autowired cause a warning in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm working on a Spring project and I'm curious about the best practices for dependency injection. Specifically, I've noticed that when I use `@Autowired`, IntelliJ IDEA gives me a warning. Can someone explain why this happens and suggest alternative approaches for dependency injection in Spring?

[here is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J622u.jpg)